# How do I allow for site specific php.ini files in each site root in MAMP?

Tags: mamp

I have a large number of local dev sites that require different settings in the php.ini file. How can I tell MAMP to allow these in each of their site roots?

Comment: maybe this will be helpful: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php

Comment: I had a look at that one before posting. It requires that I manually edit the vhost file each time a new site is spun up. I was wondering if there was a way to just allow any site to have a specific php.ini override file, if not just use the default one

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to use seperate php.ini files in the folders I wanted to effect, so in the root of each of your sites, you should be able to use different ini files...and I think you only need to use define the settings you need rather than an entire ini file

Comment: I have php.ini files in there but they do not seem to be affecting it. I have restarted apache too.

Comment: hmm, you may be using an older than 5.3 php install see here.. http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php if so than I'm afraid you'll be stuck using the vhost stuff

Comment: either way, you'll be limited as far as what can be set...some settings are required to be set in the main .ini file